# Google app script and javascript query to an internal api

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an issue with google script and html services :
Can you help me ?

I want to create a function on Google sheet to query data to an internal API. I saw that it's possible to query my data with js. But i don't succeed to create a function that can return the result on a google sheet cell.

My optimal way will be :
- having a function on Gsheet (i.e. =getvalue("name"))

- then this function open an Html files with "name" in parameter (for example in the title)
- then a javascript function query the internal API and **return the value to the first function in Gscript**.
- then the value is return by the gscript to the gsheet. Like that i can keep my formula in my cell and i have the value that can be refresh.

Is there a way to return my value from JS to Gscript in the same function ?

Thank you for your help,

Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Make sure you read the Apps Script documentation on Custom Functions and all the relevant restrictions. Namely, custom functions must be **deterministic** and require no authorization.